# Caesar Cipher in Java (Spanish Characters)

Tags: java, special-characters, encryption

I've reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821545/simple-caesar-cipher-in-java/), and I was wondering if Is there any way to consider the whole range of characters? For example, "á", "é", "ö", "ñ", and not consider " " (the [Space])? (For example, my String is "Hello World", and the standard result is "Khoor#Zruog"; I want to erase that "#", so the result would be "KhoorZruog")

I'm sure my answer is in this piece of code:

```
if (c >= 32 && c <= 127)
        {
            // Change base to make life easier, and use an
            // int explicitly to avoid worrying... cast later
            int x = c - 32;
            x = (x + shift) % 96;
            chars[i] = (char) (x + 32);
        }
```

But I've tried some things, and it didn't work.

Comment: Define "whole range". I wouldn't consider `ö`, but would include `ř` - obviously, the range definition is up to you.

Comment: Also, neither "á", "é", "ö" or "ñ" are anywhere *close* to ASCII 32-127; depending on the character set, they could be anywhere. As soon as you leave the 26 basic Latin letters, the set of characters will not form a contiguous range in the chosen encoding.

Answer (score 1):

See this pseudocode - should be trivially implementable:

```
// you need to define your own range, obviously - it's not at all obvious whether
// e.g. "ź" should be included and that it should come after "z"
array char_range = ['a','á','b','c','č', (...), 'z','ź','ž'] 
// the text to encode
string plaintext = 'some text here'
// this will contain encoded text
stringbuilder ciphertext = ''
// the classic Caesar Cipher shifts by 3 chars to the right
// to decipher, reverse the sign
int shift_by = 3 
// note: character != byte, esp. not in UTF-8 (1 char could be 1 or more bytes)
for each character in plaintext
    get character_position of character in char_range // e.g. "a" would return 0
    if not in char_range // e.g. spaces and other non-letters
        do nothing // drop character 
        // alternately, you can append it to ciphertext unmodified
        continue with next character
    add shift_by to character_position
    if character_position > char_range.length
        character_position modulo char_range.length
    if character_position < 0 // useful for decoding
        add char_range.length to character_position 
    get new_character at character_position
    append new_character to ciphertext
done
```

Comment: Of course, while this is a nice excercise, it is not really cryptography - i.e. is breakable by anyone over the age of 5, within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The Space as the ASCII Code 32 which you don't filter out. You could try:

```
if (c >= 33 && c <= 127) 
    { 
        // Change base to make life easier, and use an 
        // int explicitly to avoid worrying... cast later 
        int x = c - 32; 
        x = (x + shift) % 96; 
        chars[i] = (char) (x + 32); 
    }
```

I just changed the 32 with a 33 in your if-Clause so that the spaces are simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this. It will check for you it the given int value represents a literal.
[Character](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28int%29)

So your function could look like this:

```
if (Character.isLiteral(c) )
{
     // Change base to make life easier, and use an
     // int explicitly to avoid worrying... cast later
     int x = c - Character.MIN_VALUE;
     x = (x + shift) % Character.MAX_VALUE;
     chars[i] = (char) (x + Character.MIN_VALUE);
}
```