# java encryption

Tags: java, encryption

hey...can u please give the code for any simple encryption technique in java....please help me out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821545/simple-caesar-cipher-in-java

Comment: @Up Voters:  Can whoever chose to up vote this question get their doctor to review their medications?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the example of built-in AES usage [here](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/95-702/examples/security/AES.java) and [there](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/EncryptionanddecryptionwithAESECBPKCS7Padding.htm).

---

Updated expired Sun link.

Comment: Can you update your first link?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what type of encryption you do like to have. If you want to have easy to use production-ready encryption, you should look at [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/).