# Array, String, Data Structure to implement cesar algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

What is the best Data Structure(DS)/Class I can use to implement [Caesar's Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) ? This is what I have thought of so far:

1. String with all alphabets (abc...zABCD...Z) ?
2. Array with alphabets and wraparound ?
3. DS which stores a key value pair ?

Why i thought i need 3 - I have to find the character (which is to be encoded) in my "list of numbered alphabets". Then i use that index, and shift it by a number. I thought that it would be faster if i used key value pair instead of searching each index of string or array.

Comment: DS which stores a key value pair ? why do you need it ?

Comment: When you have your string to cipher just add the shift length to each character. Post your code, preferably a [sscce](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner.

Comment: You don't need to search each index, because the width of the shift is the same for all input characters.

Comment: @jlordo - actually, i have not implemented it yet. I need some help in deciding which of the 3 i have to use. Then, i will start coding.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName: none of the three ;) See TechExchange's answer below.

Comment: oh ! this down vote is so depressing :( do i have to show example code all the time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String applyCaesar(String text, int shift)
{
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (c >= 32 && c <= 127)
        {
            // Change base to make life easier, and use an
            // int explicitly to avoid worrying... cast later
            int x = c - 32;
            x = (x + shift) % 96;
            if (x < 0) 
              x += 96; //java modulo can lead to negative values!
            chars[i] = (char) (x + 32);
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821545/simple-caesar-cipher-in-java)