# what is the solution of my encryption decryption problem?

Tags: java, encryption

I need help in encryption/decryption in java
I wanna encrypt and decrypt in main way
for example change 'a' to 'c' and 'b' to 'g' and etc.java
how can i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple caesar cipher in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821545/simple-caesar-cipher-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the chars to ints and add a certain value to the int, then cast back to char. 
For example,

```
System.out.println((char)((int)’a’+2));
```

Would produce ‘c’ from ‘a’. It’s taking advantage of the numerical values chars are represented by. Take a look at a Unicode table.

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII. Take a look at a [Unicode table](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).